# What does it mean when Risk function turns out to be a number?

Tags: computational-statistics, frequentist, decision-theory

I have a statistical decision making theory problem.I have to calculate the Risk Function for each of 4 decision rules.However,it turns out that the fourth Risk function is not a function of θ and it is a constant number.
What does this mean?Am I supposed to compare this Risk function with the other ones or reject it?

Comment: The risk function remains a function of $\theta:$ that never changes.  Its values are constant, that's all.

Comment: One interesting case of a constant risk function is when its value is the minimax risk, because it shows that the corresponding decision is minimax.